# Faster way to pass touch through transparent views?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode

I have some objects which are just UIImageViews of PNGs with transparent areas that overlap. I stack a few images near each other where the transparent parts overlap. When one of them is touched, I play some audio.

In order to let touch pass through the transparent areas and thus let the proper object be recognized, I pass touch through transparent layers with this:

```
- (BOOL)pointInside:(CGPoint)point withEvent:(UIEvent *)event{
    unsigned char pixel[1] = {0};
    CGContextRef context = CGBitmapContextCreate(pixel, 
                                                 1, 1, 8, 1, NULL,
                                                 kCGImageAlphaOnly);
    UIGraphicsPushContext(context);
    [self.image drawAtPoint:CGPointMake(-point.x, -point.y)];
    UIGraphicsPopContext();
    CGContextRelease(context);
    CGFloat alpha = pixel[0]/255.0;
    BOOL transparent = alpha < 0.01;
    if(transparent){
        return NO;
    } else {
        return YES;
    }

}
```

The problem: when around 3 or 4 get stacked on the screen, there starts being a noticeable delay for the touch. Ie. the top layer triggers immediately, but the bottom layer takes some milliseconds.

Is there a faster way of perhaps passing the touch through transparent areas of my PNG?

Thanks